# I Keep getting Login failed for User. Error 18456 in Azure SQL

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-sql-database

I really need help on login error that keep appearing. Unable to login with error :"Login failed for user. Microsoft server error 18456"

Comment: which account did you use to login the SQL database?

Comment: Do you receive any State number along with error 18456?

Comment: I get state1 in the error 18456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found Error 18456 with State 1 only during Microsoft Azure outages. To make sure visit [@AzureSupport](https://twitter.com/AzureSupport) on Twitter or visit [Azure Status](https://status.azure.com/en-us/status). Sometimes Azure Support and Azure Status do not show any issues because issues may not be affecting a good number of customers, but you can still find out what is happening by going to Help + Support, choose Service Health, then examine "Health History" and "Resource Health" as shown on [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/resource-health-exposes-historical-health/) article.

Another possible cause of this error is the status of your Azure Subscription. Maybe your subscription requires your attention.